# Summarise returns different values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe `x`

[image: data frame]

and I need to calculate the number of steps from the 1st column by days or by certain 5-min intervals.

This code for dates works fine

[image: return for sum grouped by date]

```
b<-summarise(group_by(x,date),h = sum(steps))
```

But when I change date on interval,

```
b<-summarise(group_by(x,interval),h = sum(steps))
```

it returns only NA values

[image: return for sum grouped by interval]

Comment: From the snippet of your dataframe one can only guess. As it looks all values on date `2012-10-01` are NA. Hence, when grouping by `interval` and summarizing each group contains at least one NA, so that the sum() will be NA for each interval or group. Maybe you want sum(..., na.rm = TRUE)?

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).